Copy a PDF avoids reading from several users
I made a small function, that reads a PDF, adds some table on original PDF, then saves as a new file.
The problem is when I use it, it seems to block the original file, and several users cannot read it at the same time.
this.document = new PdfDocument();
using (PdfDocument docOri = PdfReader.Open(drawingFileName, PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly))
{
    foreach (PdfPage page in docOri.Pages)
    {
        this.currentPage = this.document.AddPage(page);
        this.graphics = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(this.currentPage);
        if (configVentilation.IsActivated)
        {
            displayVentilationTable(listDetails, configVentilation);
        }
    }
}
string filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(drawingFileName);
this.fileName = Global.GetTempFolder() + filename;
this.document.Save(this.fileName);
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(this.fileName);
Process.Start(startInfo);

It seems by using this.document.AddPage(page), original document gets used, and then other users cannot open it anymore. How can I make a copy, and "free" original file?

Consider creating a temporary copy of the PDF, modify the temp. copy and overwrite the original?

First make a copy, then work on the copy and save changes back to that copy.

@Fildor What I don't understand, is why original file is still blocked, even if I go out from using ? Or is it because I use AddPage(page), so object page is still used? May it work if instead of that I use AddPage((PdfPage)page.Clone()). Or may I have no choice to do as you and DarkBee advised?

@DarkBee I don't want to overwrite original. What I want to do is open original, modify it then save as a temporary file. But As I understood is using AddPage(page), original remains blocked even when going out from using. I believe if I use AddPage((PdfPage)page.Clone()) instead, this may work? (but cannot test on my computer). As I'm not sure, I changed as the following : Create the temporary file, then work on it, then save and open. But I'd like to understand why as the code is now, why original file is still in use, when temporary file is opened.

The file system may not lift locks immediately. That's annoying but it is what it is.

@Fildor thanks. In fact, I think easiest way is as you said. First copy, then work on copy. If you want to post an answer, I will wait confirmation from customer to validate it. Or may I just delete question? (Don't understand why some marked it as a "bad" question).

The file system doesn't always lift locks immediately as soon as the handle is freed. That's quite annoying but well known.
If you need to ensure the original is still readable while you are working on its data and you intend to save the changes to a different file anyway, the easiest (imho) way to go about it is:

Create a copy of the original.
Open and work on the copy.
Save changes back to said copy.

If something is observing the folder for new entries, you may want to copy to a "work-in-progress" folder and move the file back when you are done.

thanks, but even doing like that, it didn't work. I don't understand how this could be, as copying the file may avoid blocking the original one?

In that case it might not even have been your program that exclusively uses the file.  You may need to find a tool which can tell you what process locks the file.

in fact, my program was not guilty (and seems it was not guilty from the beginning). Anyway I changed my code as you advised, as it seems much more safe. Thanks for it.

You can read the PDF file from a stream and you can open the stream with the sharing and locking settings you need. And you can close the stream immediately after reading the PDF.
Maybe use code like this:
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

This will still lead to problems if other users open the file with read/write access or without allowing shared read access.

Can you explain with an example please? Because I tried Fildor's way, but I cannot find why it is still not working? I believed that coying first the file, this would solve the problem, but it is not. Or may post as a new question, with updated code?

@Siegfried.V It is unclear to me what the other "users" are doing with the file. If the file is accessed only by several instances of the same PDFsharp application, then it is easy to resolve with shared read-only access. But if other applications that require read/write access are also used, then there is no easy solution.

Thanks. In fact, the problem was not from me, but from customer... using Fildor's method solved the problem.
